# Compare multiple Pandas DataFrames for matching values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a month-over-month analysis of a car service, to report on mileage of cars in its fleet.

I have reports based in Excel, and want to use Pandas to output a wide table, reporting on the a car's usage in miles for the months reported.

For example, I have reports for January, February, March, and April. Each car has a unique vehicle identification ID (VIN), and each month accumulates miles or not. If the car isn't used, it is omitted from the report. Reports for January - April look something like:

January:

```
df_jan
+------+---------+----------+
| VIN  | Mileage |    HQ    |
+------+---------+----------+
| 1111 |     700 | Seattle  |
| 1112 |     250 | Seattle  |
| 1113 |     640 | Portland |
+------+---------+----------+
```

February:

```
df_feb
+------+---------+----------+
| VIN  | Mileage |    HQ    |
+------+---------+----------+
| 1111 |     220 | Seattle  |
| 1112 |     860 | Seattle  |
| 1114 |     120 | Portland |
| 1115 |     520 | Portland |
| 1116 |     100 | Seattle  |
+------+---------+----------+
```

March:

```
df_mar
+------+---------+----------+
| VIN  | Mileage |    HQ    |
+------+---------+----------+
| 1111 |      20 | Seattle  |
| 1112 |      40 | Seattle  |
| 1114 |     350 | Portland |
| 1116 |     140 | Seattle  |
| 1117 |      50 | Seattle  |
+------+---------+----------+
```

April:

```
df_apr
+------+---------+----------+
| VIN  | Mileage |    HQ    |
+------+---------+----------+
| 1112 |     430 | Seattle  |
| 1114 |     140 | Portland |
| 1116 |     420 | Seattle  |
| 1117 |     530 | Seattle  |
| 1118 |     220 | Bellevue |
+------+---------+----------+
```

The result I'm going for shows a column for each month, with the mileage included if the car accumulated mileage for that month:

```
df_final
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| VIN  | Jan Mileage | Feb Mileage | Mar Mileage | Apr Mileage |    HQ    |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
| 1111 |         700 |         220 |          20 |             | Seattle  |
| 1112 |         250 |         860 |          40 |         430 | Seattle  |
| 1113 |         640 |             |             |             | Portland |
| 1114 |             |         120 |         350 |         140 | Portland |
| 1115 |             |         520 |             |             | Portland |
| 1116 |             |         100 |         140 |         420 | Seattle  |
| 1117 |             |             |          50 |         530 | Seattle  |
| 1118 |             |             |             |         220 | Bellevue |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

Once I have this, I can plot and report mileage over time in a concise manner.

How can I compare VIN values (where VIN is *not* the index to the DataFrame()), and have the mileage for each month in the appropriate column? I'm able to iterate through the *first* DataFrame (January), and identify whether or not the value exists on the second DataFrame (February). But, I'm trying to avoid a lot of nested loops.

Is there a built-in method or well-known pattern to iterate through each of the DataFrames, without pre-supplying a list of values to search for, that can identify the indexes in each DataFrame, and update or skip row cells depending on whether that value was found or not?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I've updated my question. Mainly, I would like to avoid a lot of nested loops, or having to provide a list of VINs upfront to iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=pd%20merge):

```
import pandas as pd

df_jan = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1111, 1112, 1113], "Mileage": [700, 250, 640],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"]})

df_feb = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1111, 1112, 1114, 1115, 1116], "Mileage": [220, 860, 120, 520, 100],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Portland", "Seattle"]})

df_mar = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1111, 1112, 1114, 1116, 1117], "Mileage": [20, 40, 350, 140, 50],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle"]})

df_apr = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1112, 1114, 1116, 1117, 1118], "Mileage": [430, 140, 420, 530, 220],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Bellevue"]})

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["VIN", "HQ"])

df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_jan, on=["VIN", "HQ"], how="outer")
df.rename(columns={"Mileage": "Jan Mileage"}, inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_feb, on=["VIN", "HQ"], how="outer")
df.rename(columns={"Mileage": "Feb Mileage"}, inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_mar, on=["VIN", "HQ"], how="outer")
df.rename(columns={"Mileage": "Mar Mileage"}, inplace=True)

df = pd.merge(left=df, right=df_apr, on=["VIN", "HQ"], how="outer")
df.rename(columns={"Mileage": "Apr Mileage"}, inplace=True)

df = df[["VIN", "Jan Mileage", "Feb Mileage", "Mar Mileage", "Apr Mileage", "HQ"]]
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly. It takes an operation that previously took 30-60 seconds and trimmed it down to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [functools reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to get one liner join:

```py
# imports
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

# define dataframes
df_jan = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1111, 1112, 1113], 
                       "Mileage": [700, 250, 640],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"]})

df_feb = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1111, 1112, 1114, 1115, 1116],
                       "Mileage": [220, 860, 120, 520, 100],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Portland", "Seattle"]})

df_mar = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1111, 1112, 1114, 1116, 1117], 
                       "Mileage": [20, 40, 350, 140, 50],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle"]})

df_apr = pd.DataFrame({"VIN": [1112, 1114, 1116, 1117, 1118], 
                       "Mileage": [430, 140, 420, 530, 220],
                       "HQ": ["Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Bellevue"]})

# create a list of dataframes and a list of months
dfs = [df_jan, df_feb, df_mar, df_apr]
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']

# ranmes Mileage column
for df, m in zip(dfs, months):
    df.rename(columns={'Mileage':f'Mileage_{m}'}, inplace=True)

# Join all dataframes
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['VIN', 'HQ'], how='outer'), dfs)

# check result
df_final
   VIN  Mileage_Jan        HQ  Mileage_Feb  Mileage_Mar  Mileage_Apr
0  1111        700.0   Seattle        220.0         20.0          NaN
1  1112        250.0   Seattle        860.0         40.0        430.0
2  1113        640.0  Portland          NaN          NaN          NaN
3  1114          NaN  Portland        120.0        350.0        140.0
4  1115          NaN  Portland        520.0          NaN          NaN
5  1116          NaN   Seattle        100.0        140.0        420.0
6  1117          NaN   Seattle          NaN         50.0        530.0
7  1118          NaN  Bellevue          NaN          NaN        220.0
```